# JavaScript onmouseleave and onmouseenter working in Firefox and IE9 but not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

I was trying to create a table which have several links which appear onHover and hides again onleave. I implemented these 2 functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hide(cls, no) {
        var select = '.' + cls + no;
        $(select).hide();
    }
    function show(cls, no) {
        var select = '.' + cls + no;
        $(select).show();
    }           
</script>
```

and my HTML Code is

```
<tr onmouseenter="show('inv', 1)" onmouseleave="hide('inv', 1)" >   
    <td width="30%">
            <a class="single_image" href="img/img1-big.png"><span class="icon-picture"></span> Image1.jpg</a>
        </td>
        <td width="40%" align="center">
        <div class="button-col">
            <a href="#" class="inline-buttons inv1"><span class="icon-pencil"></span> Rename </a>
            <a href="#" class="inline-buttons inv1"><span class="icon-arrow-down"></span> Download </a>
            <a href="#" class="inline-buttons inv1"><span class="icon-share"></span> Share </a>
            <a href="#" class="inline-buttons inv1"><span class="icon-trash"></span> Delete </a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am Using Bootstrap framework.
This code works perfectly on IE9 and Firefox

Comment: Are you using any bootstrap javascript? In that case, jQuery is already required and you can benefit from that when doing stuff like this.

Comment: I don't know jquery very well. And no, I am not using jquery. But yes I have imported jquery files from code.jquery.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events is not available in chrome (and other browsers). You should use a javascript framework that normalizes this, like jQuery.

Using jQuery, try something like:

```
<tr data-no="1" data-cls="inv">
```

And:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr').each(function() {
        var $target = $('.' + $(this).data('cls') + $(this).data('no'));
        $(this).hover(
            function() { $target.show(); },
            function() { $target.hide(); }
        );
    });
});
```

More info on `.hover()`: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

More information about compat here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Can you help in Coding such thing in JQuery, I just need an example to get close to my solution. I am not very much expert at JS.

Comment: Worked :)
Just need to add mouse leave now.
Thanks